# Can I store a function's output parameter into a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have the following code:

```
class Thing
{};

void fnc(Thing** out)
{
    *out = new Thing();
};
```

Where `fnc` returns a new instance of `Thing` via output parameter. Normally I'd use it as follows:

```
int main()
{
    Thing* thing;
    fnc(&thing);  
}
```

Can I put the returned object in a `std::unique_ptr` instead?

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Thing> uniqueThing;
    fnc(???);
}
```

Comment: You need an indirection, pass the raw pointer to unique_ptr.

Comment: Why not return a pointer from the function?

Comment: @molbdnilo good point. Let's pretend for now the function returns a status code or something similar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the raw pointer in the `unique_ptr` so that the `unique_ptr` takes ownership:

```
Thing* thing;
fnc(&thing);
std::unique_ptr<Thing> thing_unique (thing);
```

Comment: assuming you can change the API contract of fnc

Answer (score 7):

To extend your code sample, it (i.e. pass-by-pointer) would be

```
void fnc(std::unique_ptr<Thing>* out)
{
    out->reset(new Thing());
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Thing> uniqueThing;
    fnc(&uniqueThing);  
}
```

or use pass-by-reference:

```
void fnc(std::unique_ptr<Thing>& out)
{
    out.reset(new Thing());
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Thing> uniqueThing;
    fnc(uniqueThing);  
}
```

But I think return the pointer by return value would be more clear:

```
std::unique_ptr<Thing> fnc()
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Thing>(new Thing);
    // or
    // return std::make_unique<Thing>();
};

int main()
{
    auto uniqueThing = fnc();
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of outputting pointers/references to unique_ptr directly!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that directly. You'll have to use a temporary variable:

```
Thing* thing{};
fnc(&thing);

uniqueThing.reset(*thing);
```

Or even better, because `fnc` doesn't a return an error code or something else, you can just return the new pointer which let's write initialize `uniqueThing` directly:

```
std::unique_ptr<Thing> uniqueThing{fnc()};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the pointer first from `fnc` and then create the `unique_ptr`, something like:

```
Thing* tmp;
find(&tmp);
std::unique_ptr<Thing> thing(tmp);
```